# discord bot list all roles python

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I have this code

```
async def allroles(ctx):
  output2 = ""
  server = ctx.message.guild
  role_id = server.roles[0]

  for role in server.roles:
    if role_id == 640586288029892618:
      print("it´s everyone role")
    else:
      output2 +=f"{role.name} \n"
  await ctx.send(output2)
```

where 640586288029892618 == @everyone
I wanna write every role except everyone, but when I tried this it just wrote all roles include everyone, so I guess my try to not write it was wrong (and if there is option to instead ID of everyone use role_name so I don´t have to change it for every @everyone server role but write into

```
if role.name == "@everyone":
    Skip
else:
    output2 +=f"{role.name} \n"
await ctx.send(output2)
```

It would be nice.  Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you are doing something wrong here

```
    if role_id == 640586288029892618:
      print("it´s everyone role")
```

The `role_id = server.roles[0]` returns the some weird data here(I Don't remember the name)
so try replacing `if role_id == 640586288029892618:` with `if role_id.id == 640586288029892618:`

hope it solves your problem, else just ping me up

**Edit:**
since u asked for a easier method than putting role id every time

well for most of the roles it may work fine but when u put emojis in role names u might face difficulty while naming roles in code, and why go for hard coding when u can do it by simply adding another argument like
Make sure u import **Role** Class

```
    async def allroles(ctx, role_to_check:Role):
          //some code here
          for role in server.roles:
            if role.id == role_to_check.id:
               print("it´s everyone role")
```

Hope this solves your answer man :)

Comment: I deleted `role_id = server.roles[0]` and replaced `role_id` with `role.id` and it's working, but still wondering if there is option instead ID use name (instead 640586288029892618 use @everyone)

Comment: `if role.name == "@everyone":` working fine so I can say it's solved but can you put it up?

Comment: and please upvote and mark my answer  right if it solved your problem else just ping me up again ;)